# Validation using isalpha for a loop

Tags: c, while-loop, alphabetical

I am making a program in C that involves the selection of 4 options.
However, I am unable to validate to check whether the value of the variable Option is a letter or number other than 1,2,3 or 4. When I enter a letter it continues to loop the print statement but not the input function and I am unable to carry on with my program.
Could someone please tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
int Option;

while( (Option>4) || ( isalpha(Option) ) )


{

printf("Please select a valid option from the 4 options listed above! \n");

scanf(" %d",&Option);

}
```

Comment: does `Option` hold a character or integer value ? In the former case, you should probably compare with `'4'` instead of `4`. In the latter case, `isalpha` won't do what you expect.

Comment: You **need** to check the return value of the scanf call: `if (scanf("%d", &Option) != 1) { fprintf(stderr, "error in scanf on line %d.\n", __LINE__); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }`

Comment: You cannot use your `scanf` to both input numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...) and letters ('a', 'b', ... 'A', 'B', ...). I suggest you read user input with `fgets()` instead, and parse the input afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for trying to explain. I think I will take your advice and read up on that. =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [description for the function `isalpha()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4.1.2) states that

> In the "C" locale, isalpha returns true only for the characters for which isupper or islower is true.

Which means that

```
isalpha('4') // false
isalpha(4) // false in ASCII-based computers
           // the ASCII table assigns 4 to a control character
isalpha('A') // true
isalpha(65) // true in ASCII-based computers
            // the ASCII table assigns 65 to the symbol 'A'
```

Comment: Don't forget to mention why `isalpha(65)` returns true ;)

Comment: Hi,
Could you please explain it more simply? I sort of get the fact that it basically only applies to characters which can be capitalised or lower-cased. However, I am not sure how to validate this either with this method or any other.